# SQL: replace with few records (mysql)

Tags: sql, mysql, replace

There's an index table. (Links tags with ids).

```
REPLACE INTO com_index (word, ids) VALUES ('word1', concat(ids, ' 2')), ('word2', concat(ids, ' 2'))
```

`word` is a primary key.

I try to look through rows, add ' 2' to `ids` in those of them, which exist; and create a new row with ' 2' if it doesn't.

So, I need to look if there's any row with such word column (word1 or word2 ...) and concat ' 2' to thier ids. And if there is no such rows (with such `word` column) - create it with `ids` = ' 2'.

And it's MySQL! (there's no sub_selects)

Comment: I think a bit of background of the problem you are trying to solve, and a couple of concrete examples with example input and output would help.

Comment: There's an idea. INSERT IGNORE all words. And then UPDADE them all.

Comment: a little corection: MySQL supports subselects since version 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple solution that is possible because `word` is the primary key*:

```
INSERT INTO `com_index` (word, ids)
VALUES ('word1', '2'), ('word2', '2')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ids=concat(ids, ' 2')
```

Make sure to check the [MySQL Manual for the `INSERT ... ON` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

---

*actually, it is also possible with other kinds of indexes, as long as they're unique (which is given with a primary key

Comment: Thanks, it feels like it's the best solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`replace into` inserts or updates entire rows.  I don't think you can use it to do an update that depends on the current value of a column.

You could do it in two statements, like:

```
UPDATE com_index SET ids = concat(ids,' 2')  
    WHERE word = 'word1'
    AND ids <> '2'           -- Only 2
    AND ids not like '2 %'   -- Starts with 2
    AND ids not like '% 2 %' -- 2 in the middle
    AND ids not like '% 2';  -- 2 at the end
INSERT INTO com_index (word, ids) 
    SELECT 'word1', '2'
    FROM dual
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from com_index where word = 'word1');
```

As you can see, storing a list in a column gets tricky fast.  Consider splitting the com_index table into two tables with a foreign key relation.

Comment: You've understood me wrong. I mean by 'in those of them, which exist' - exist at all. So, I need to look if there's any row with such `word` column (`word1` or `word2` ...) and add concat ' 2' to thier `ids`. And if there is no such row - create it.

Comment: And it's MySQL! (there's no sub selects)

Comment: That's what this code does?  It modifies a row if it exists, then creates it if it doesn't exist.  If you don't need to check for '2', you can remove the four lines that start with AND from the answer

Comment: Right, it needs a `from dual` like Oracle.  I've tested the current version and it works.  The MySQL manual page for subqueries is here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html

Comment: Thanks, never knew, there is subqueries.